# Cosmic entanglement background?

Tags: cosmology, quantum-entanglement

Could we measure the entanglement (if any!) of the cosmic microwave (neutrino, graviton,...) background radiation?
Related to this: does the LCDM model of Cosmology predict something about cosmic quantum entanglement?

Answer (score 0):

[Entanglement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_entanglement) is a fashionable word /shorthand to describe a subset of what is  in reality  one quantum mechanical wavefunction. In  this sense the [inflation period](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflation_(cosmology)) in cosmology that is modeled with an effective quantum mechanical theory

> [This theory allows](https://www.physicsoftheuniverse.com/topics_bigbang_inflation.html) for some kind of very slight unevenness (so-called quantum fluctuations) on a sub-atomic scale at a very early stage in the growth of the universe which provided starting points for the large-scale structures we see in today’s universe. This suggests the rather bizarre possibility that the largest structures in the universe, the great clusters of galaxies, may actually have been spawned by sub-microscopic seeds.

So quantum fluctuations are associated with galaxies and clusters of galaxies, so in a sense quantum correlations, are observed.

If you are talking of entanglement in the sense of two galaxies at opposite sides can be shown to be entangled, it is a different story, though [correlations](https://www.newscientist.com/article/dn23301-planck-shows-almost-perfect-cosmos-plus-axis-of-evil/) are seen in the cosmic microwave background, it would not be something testable with individual particles anyway.